# Initialization of a UIViewController with default values consisted of singletons

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, uiviewcontroller, initialization, singleton

Trying to refactor my code in order to avoid having to reference shared instances all over the place, rather I'd like to inject them via a custom initializer. My limited understanding of initilazation in Swift is preventing me to do so.

Here's my ViewController, minus the methods and boilerplate:

```
class LoginVC: UIViewController {
    let dataManager: DataManager
    let restManager: RestManager
    let defaults: UserDefaults

    init(defaults: UserDefaults = .standard, dataManager: DataManager = .sharedInstance, restManager: RestManager = .sharedInstance) {
      self.defaults = defaults
      self.dataManager = dataManager
      self.restManager = restManager
      super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
   }
}
```

I've provided default values which are shared instances declared as a static constant in their respective singleton classes of DataManager and RestManager. Was planning to do this in each and every ViewController that has these singletons referenced in them. Anyways, my problem arises as the compiler complains that I must provide a required initializer init(coder: aDecoder).

No problem, but after implementing...

```
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

... the compiler once again complains, this time that

> Blockquote Property 'self.defaults' not initialized at super.init call

Which I guess makes sense since the required init? is, as far as I know, a delegating init (could be that I'm totally mistaken here). I do not know how to pass the default params of my custom init to the super init of this initializer, or if that's even possible.

I have tried a workaround though by changing the constants to mutable variables and by making them implicitly unwrapped like so:

```
class LoginVC: UIViewController {
    var dataManager: DataManager!
    var restManager: RestManager!
    var defaults: UserDefaults!

    init(defaults: UserDefaults = .standard, dataManager: DataManager = .sharedInstance, restManager: RestManager = .sharedInstance) {
      self.defaults = defaults
      self.dataManager = dataManager
      self.restManager = restManager
      super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
   }
   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder) 
   }
}
```

This workaround actually manages to compile and build, but the app crashes as soon as userDefaults which are in viewDidLoad are unwrapped because they have a nil value. All of them have nil values even though they are defaulted in the params of the custom initializer which leads me to believe that I've royally screwed up.

Any help/clarification would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that this is what you would like to do, but I would suggest you this solution

```
extension UIViewController {

    var defaults: UserDefaults {
        get {
            return .standard
        }
    }
}
```

and so in each `UIViewController` you can do `self.defaults`

If you want some of your `UIViewControllers` to have another references, you can do this

```
//create protocol with all vars
protocol References {
    var defaults: UserDefaults {get}
}

//create extension with default implementation
extension References {
    var defaults: UserDefaults {
        get {
            return .standard
        }
    }
}

//add this protocol to all UIViewControllers
extension UIViewController: References {
}

//or create new class with references
class ReferenceViewController: UIViewController, References {
}

//override reference in some view controller if needed 
class AnotherReferencesViewController: UIViewController { //or ReferenceViewController 
    var defaults: UserDefaults {
        get {
            //something new
            return .standard
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's for the idea of injecting them via Protocols, I've implemented this and it works like a charm! Still not sure why my way didn't work but thanks once again though.